# Loading local webpage website iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios4

Hello everyone I have a local website in my iphone app with images/css/jquery. If I open the html file from my pc browser it opens everything is displayed properly.[image]

Here is my code to load the html contents in uiwebview which is not working.

```
/    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"HTML1"]];
//    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//    [_webView loadRequest:request];
//    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"HTML1"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    [_webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

Neither of the above is working ant help :) ?

Comment: Does `htmlFile` actually contain the path to test.html? Unless you're explicitly copying the file to a HTML1 directory you shouldn't use the `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` but instead use `pathForResource:ofType:`

Comment: Hello sorry i didnt get you .. sorry i am new to pathdirectory.

Comment: Print out the `htmlFile` variable using `NSLog(@"%@", htmlFile);` and make sure it is not `nil`. Specifying HTML1 as a directory is not needed as the groups in the Xcode project navigator are not copied to the app bundle, therefore test.html will be in the root of your app bundle.

Comment: Hello the path is not nil u were right its in the root directory. I can see the path to the html file.
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];

 NSLog(htmlFile);

Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/qqqqqqqqqq/test.app/test.html

Comment: and  the uiwebview it still blank.

Comment: Hmm, this is working fine for me. Your `_webView` is not `nil` is it?

Comment: Hello i did a Noslog and i got the following  this  WEBVIEW = <UIWebView: 0xa5a8960; frame = (0 0; 768 960); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5a8a10>>. mean its not nil. I am using  ipad simulator

Comment: NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
 
 //Create a URL object.
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 
 //URL Requst Object
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 
 //Load the request in the UIWebView.
 [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
its displaying correctly

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Put the test.html under the Pages-HTML folder Directly...**
**and then to load the html file in UIWebview use code...**

```
    // to load html file from the bundle
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"helpfile" ofType:@"html"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [self.webVw loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```